# Anonymous functions not working in PHP 5.5.x

Tags: php, cakephp, anonymous-function

So, here is a small code snippet from my project

```
if (!empty($user['IndustryUser'])) {
    $user['IndustryUser'] = array_filter($user['IndustryUser'], function ($ku) {
        $k = !empty($ku['Industry']['name']) ? trim($ku['Industry']['name']): '';
        return $k != '';
    });


    $userIndustries = array();
    foreach ($user['IndustryUser'] as $ku) {
        $userIndustries[] = $ku;
    }
    $user['IndustryUser'] = $userIndustries;
}
```

This code is present inside a Model named `User.php`. And also there is a shell script named `FetchIndustriesShell.php` inside `app/console/command`, which makes use of this Model.
When I run this script from the command line, as `cake FetchIndustries`, I get the following error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in D:\wamp\www\industry-svn\
app\Model\User.php on line 203
```

where Line 203, is where the anonymous function is defined(line 2 from code snippet).

What i tried is

1) Run phpinfo() inside bootstrap.php to verify the php version. It shows `PHP 5.5.12` (attached is the screenshot).

2) I installed xampp,to verify if my wampp installtion/php libraries had problem. But I still got the same error.

3) Also referred https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/issues/134. But that did not help either.

- **CakePHP Version used is: 2.5.1**
- **Project currently running on: wampp (local)**
  [image]

Comment: Seeing as the issue only presents itself when you run it from the command line, it stands to reason that the `cake` command is using the wrong PHP binary

Comment: Check your PHP environment that `cake` is using. Fire `php -v` on your terminal. It will give you the php version in use on the command line. The PHP version needs to be the same as the one you see in your `phpinfo()`

Comment: Thank you guys, that worked for me. I did not know about the PHP env for the command line. It was 5.2.x. Replaced it, Gave path to the new PHP lib by changing the environment variable.